# Cannot access 'variable_name' before initialization

Tags: svelte

When using reactive variables by declaring them using the `$:` syntax, you get the following error.

`Cannot access 'variable_name' before initialization`

Here is the code:

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import { ledzep, redhotchilis } from './data.js'
    
    $: bandmembers = [...ledzep, ...redhotchilis]
    
    let namesWithA = bandmembers.filter(d => {
            if (d.indexOf('a') > 0) {               
                return true;
            }
        else {
            return false
        }
    })
    
</script>
<h2>Band Members</h2>
<ul>
{#each bandmembers as member}
    <li>{member}</li>
{/each}
</ul>

<h2>Members with "A" in their names</h2>
<ul>
{#each namesWithA as member}
    <li>{member}</li>
{/each}
</ul>
```

**data.js**

```js
export const ledzep = ["Jimmy Page", "John Bonham", "Robert Plant", "John Paul Jones"]
export const redhotchilis = ["Anthony Kiedis", "Flea", "Chad Smith", "Josh Klinghoffer"]
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you assign variables using `$:` you cannot assign them as part of other variables declared using `let`, `const`, or `var`.

**When you do assignments using `$:`, you can only use them in other variables assigned using `$:`**. In the code posted above, you need to change the following lines:

```js
let namesWithA = bandmembers.filter(d => {
    if (d.indexOf('a') > 0) {               
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
})
```

to the following:

```js
$: namesWithA = bandmembers.filter(d => {
    if (d.indexOf('a') > 0) {               
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
})
```

It took me a while to figure this out and just wanted to share this with any other **Svelte** newbies that are starting out in this new technology.

Comment: Just noting that in this example, you don't need to use `$:` at all, since `ledzep` and `redhotchilis` aren't reactive variables (values imported from another module are taken to be constant)

Comment: It's interesting that if the variable is coming as a parameter, used in the function body and then declared with let, it will raise the error too.